# which package has griddata?scipy or matplotlib.mlab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I ran my teacher's code and got wrong that it said cannot import name 'griddata' from 'matplot.mlab', i coded then 'from scipy import griddata' and it got 'griddata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interp' because there is a line 'z = griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi,interp='linear')'.
i don't know how to modify this code

here is the code :

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata  # i used 'from scipy.interpolate import griddata' , and it could work ,but showed error '

x = np.genfromtxt(sys.argv[2], usecols=(0))
y = np.genfromtxt(sys.argv[2], usecols=(1))
z = np.genfromtxt(sys.argv[2], usecols=(2))

xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
```

when i ran it got error  'griddata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interp'. I changed ' interp' to 'method' because scipy.doc shows it can use (method='linear'),but it also got error 'griddata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'.

Comment: `from scipy.interpolate import griddata`?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html  It seems that functions that are in scipy or numpy are now removed from `matplotlib.mlab`.

Comment: can you show the code?